# IOException generated when I run the following code for check the internet availability

Tags: java

I developed an application in which I check the internet connection monitoring continuously. When I run the application and internet/WiFi is available no Exceptions occur. An issue occurs as soon as WiFi or Internet disconnects.

```
private void detectnetworkloss() {
    Thread timer=new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
    for(;;) {
    //InetSocketAddress address= new InetSocketAddress("www.google.com",80); 
            try{
       Socket socket=null;
        String host="www.google.com";
        int port=80;
        int timeOutInMilliSec=5000;
        socket= new Socket();        
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeOutInMilliSec);
        socket.close();
            wifi.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Resources/images/connect1.png")));
            }catch(IOException e){
                wifi.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Resources/images/disconnect1.png")));
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try{
        sleep(100);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){   
        //e.printStackTrace();
        }      
    }  
    }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

Exception as follows:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at turbine_stats.Main_Frame$2.run(Main_Frame.java:235)
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at turbine_stats.Main_Frame$2.run(Main_Frame.java:235)
```

Please assist me in solving it?

Regards

Comment: Hello, please consider. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: grammar and code formatting

Answer (score 0):

It is what is says on the tin - you get `No route to host` exception if there's no internet, which I guess is what you are after - you expect this to happen and catch IOException (SocketTimeoutException is subclass of IOException). Although I don't think you need to call e.printStackTrace() in the catch block. Catch it, detect disconnect, go on.